# ¿Para qué sirve PostResponseAsyncTask?

Tags: java, android

Tengo una duda... para que sirve o que es lo que hace PostResponseAsyncTask en Android, tengo una linea de código que lo utiliza pero no se que es lo que hace, espero me puedan ayudar, gracias..

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    HashMap DataAlumno = new HashMap();

    DataAlumno.put("id", MatAlumReg.getText().toString());
    DataAlumno.put("user", NomAlumnReg.getText().toString());
    DataAlumno.put("pass", ContAlumReg.getText().toString());
    DataAlumno.put("carrera", Carrera.getText().toString());
    DataAlumno.put("rango", "1");

    PostResponseAsyncTask TaskInsertAlum = new PostResponseAsyncTask(
        RegAlumnoActivity.this, DataAlumno, 
        new AsyncResponse() {
            @Override
            public void processFinish(String s) {
                Log.d(LOGAlumReg, s);

                if(s.contains("\"success\":1,\"message\":\"El usuario se ha agregado correctamente\"")){
                    Toast.makeText(RegAlumnoActivity.this, 
                                   "Alumno Registrado Correctamente...",
                                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    Intent HaciaInterfazAlumno = new Intent(
                        RegAlumnoActivity.this, 
                        InterfazAlumnoActivity.class
                    );

                    startActivity(HaciaInterfazAlumno);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(RegAlumnoActivity.this, 
                        "No se pudo registrar el alumno, Intentelo nuevamente...",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    );

    TaskInsertAlum.execute("http://aludoc.com/reg/registro.php");
}
```

Comment: Creaste alguna clase llamada asi? Ademas como consejo OJO como declaras las variables, recuerda que las mayusculas generalmente se utilizan para los tipos de variables (HashMap) y las minusculas para el objeto creado (dataAlumno)

Answer (score 0):

Es una clase que pertenece a una librería  particular llamada **[`generic_asynctask`](https://github.com/kosalgeek/generic_asynctask)** (no es oficial de Android), la cual se encuentra alojada en Github.

Según su autor:

```
PostResponseAsyncTask (Contexto contexto, AsyncResponse asyncResponse)
```

> Tienes que al menos llamar a este constructor y pasarle dos
>   argumentos `Contexto` y un objeto `AsyncResponse` que por lo
>   general se puede hacer por una clase anónima. Tenga en cuenta que el
>   `AsyncResponse` es también **mi interfaz personalizada que no forma
>   parte de la biblioteca de Android en absoluto**.
>
> Esta clase se utiliza para obtener datos en Cadena desde un resultado
>   de la web. Debido a que es asíncrono, puede obtener los datos a través
>   del método `AsyncReponse` llamado `processFinish` (cadena de salida).
>   En el método, obtiene los datos a través de la variable 'output'
>   String.

[Aquí tienes el enlace a dicha biblioteca en Github](https://github.com/kosalgeek/generic_asynctask#postresponseasynctaskcontext-context-asyncresponse-asyncresponse).

Answer (score 0):

[PostResponseASyncTask](https://github.com/kosalgeek/generic_asynctask/blob/master/AsyncTask/app/src/main/java/com/kosalgeek/asynctask/PostResponseAsyncTask.java) es una clase que implemente AsyncTask, en realidad tiene el funcionamiento de un AsyncTask ya que tiene implementados los mètodos

```
  @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() { 
    ...

 @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls){
    ...

@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    ...
```

pero aùn tiene otros mètodos implementados para poder leer .xml o .json

> tengo una linea de codigo que lo utiliza pero no se que es lo que
>   hace, espero me puedan ayudar, gracias..

Despues de instanciar `PostResponseAsyncTask`, definiendo los valores correctos que son necesarios para obtener una respuesta del WebService :

```
    PostResponseAsyncTask TaskInsertAlum = new PostResponseAsyncTask(RegAlumnoActivity.this, DataAlumno, new AsyncResponse() {
...


defines la url del WebService:

    TaskInsertAlum.execute("http://aludoc.com/reg/registro.php");
```

---

He revisado la library y te puedo comentar que si no funciona deberìas probar primeramente el correcto funcionamiento del WebService que creaste, asegura que los parametros necesarios y sus valores son correctos:

```
 DataAlumno.put("id", MatAlumReg.getText().toString());
        DataAlumno.put("user", NomAlumnReg.getText().toString());
        DataAlumno.put("pass", ContAlumReg.getText().toString());
        DataAlumno.put("carrera", Carrera.getText().toString());
        DataAlumno.put("rango", "1");
```

puedes probar simulando una petición para asegurarte funciona correctamente, recuerda que PostResponseAsyncTask, realiza peticiones POST.